# If I change my material dependency in android from version 1.0.0 to 1.3.0 then the Button color changes. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android

**If i use material version 1.0.0 colorAccent is set as default color of my all buttons but if I use material version 1.3.0 or 1.4.0 then the color of the button changes to light red color. Why is this behavior?
N.B: I have tried colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent to set to "Red" but still the button color seems to be broken and button is then light red color**

Here is the styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
     <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppBaseTheme.Toolbar</item>
     <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/someFont</item>
     <item name="fontFamily">@font/kohinoor_normal</item>
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ButtonStyle">
      <item name="android:state_pressed">true</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/oval_button</item>
      <item name="android:state_focused">true</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/color1</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/someTextSize</item>
  </style>
```

Here is the button portion code

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_accept"
     style="@style/ButtonStyle"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/some_dimension"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/some_dimension"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:text="Accept"
     android:visibility="visible" />
```

[image: Here is the button image]

Comment: try removing tint from the button by setting `app:backgroundTint=@null`

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have set the code below in styles.xml to gain the effect in all the buttons.
 <item name="backgroundTint">@color/color_i_want</item> in styles.xml 
Do you have any idea why it occurs? @DrHowdyDoo

Comment: If i set backgroundTint=@null, when button disabled (android:enabled="false") then the button color doesn't change but the disabled state is functional.

Comment: yeah u have to handle all the states manually if u are setting a background for the material button.